# Link with only background

Tags: css

I have a strange trouble with css.

Take a look at the first element of the menù (Home) of this site (is a beta): http://nightly.gamempire.it/

I want to remove the "Home" word from the first element (and leave only the house icon).
I tried removing the word, but it break the style of the element.

If I set to the property

```
body > nav a.master { width: 30px; overflow: hidden; }
```

it break the style of all the menù.

What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: also you'll have to set the width and height manually.

Comment: ok, but it remain a few pixels up to the element

Comment: @OscarFanelli as Torr3nt said, set `ul{font-size:0}`.

Comment: if I set the font-size:0 to the ul, i can't display the text of the other elements of the menù

Comment: if your icone is not from a sprite image, then put it in <a> and use vertical-align:middle; Use the alt attribute of image for your text.

Comment: the icon is in a sprite image, but this is not a real problem... the problem is the hide the text of the first element of the menù

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to do this:

```
nav li:first-child a {text-indent: -9999px;}
```

or also

```
nav li a.master {text-indent: -9999px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
body > nav li {
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }
        body > nav a.master {
          display: block;
          height: 36px;
          font-size: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
```

[image]